# How to stop contacts and recent call log from syncing?

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, contacts, sync

I am facing a problem. My recent call log list and contacts start loading for 30-40 mins or even hours. Meanwhile I cant see any of my contacts. Its very irritaing. Dont know what is the issue. Can anybody figure out what could it be?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stop syncing the contacts, go to Settings->Applications->System->Google Contacts Sync->Disable->OK.
I had a similar problem wherein I got force close warnings every 3-4 seconds.

If more than one apps are syncing your contacts then you must also uncheck those features from Accounts group in Settings.
Or you can just turn off background data.